# is there a way to check for height of an element after content loads from the server

Tags: angular

I have an angular app where data is fetched from firebase firestore. In each component, i am dynamically setting background strokes depending on the height and width of the component. The problem is that, in components where the data loads from the server, the height does not calculate with regards to the data. I am using a directive to calculate the width and height and set the strokes

Reading around, i have found changeDetectionRef being mentioned a lot but i have no clue on how to implement it. Below is my code (directive)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Renderer2, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

import { strokes } from '@constants/strokes';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appStrokes]'
})
export class StrokesDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    const width = element.offsetWidth;
    const height = element.offsetHeight;

    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      'background',
      this.randomize(width, height)
    );
  }

  private randomize(width: number, height: number): string {
    let random = this.randomProperties(width, height);

    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      random += ', ' + this.randomProperties(width, height);
    }

    return random;
  }

  private randomProperties(offsetWidth: number, offsetHeight: number): string {
    // url property
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * strokes.length);
    const url = strokes[i];

    // position property
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * offsetWidth) + 'px ';
    const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * offsetHeight) + 'px/';
    const position = x + y;

    // size property
    const h = 'auto ';
    const w = Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50) + 'px ';
    const size = w + h;

    // repeat property
    const repeat = 'no-repeat';

    // return properties
    return url + position + size + repeat;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply put the code you have in `ngAfterViewInit()` into its own method, and call that method on the callback from your Firebase call. For example if you were calling an API using `HttpClient`:

```
result$ = this.httpClient.get('/foo');
result$.subscribe(res => {
  this.updateBackgroundColour();
});
```